# Get data-attribute from element that's found with get()

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I feel like I am missing something completely and I can't figure out what. I try to get the data attribute of an item that's specified with an index through .get(). However, I can't seem to do so:

```js
var int = 1,
  selector = $("a");
    
console.log(selector.get(int));
console.log(selector.get(int).data("banana")); // Uncaught TypeError: selector.get(...).data is not a function
console.log(selector.get(int)[0].data("banana")); // Uncaught TypeError: selector.get(...).data is not a function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-banana="5">Hello</a>
<a href="#" data-banana="2">there</a>
```

What am I missing here? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) at this context,

```
console.log(selector.get(int)[0].dataset.banana);
```

Because `node` object does not have a method called `data()` in its prototype. That is a function belongs to jquery object.

If you want to travel along with jquery at this situation then you have to use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
console.log(selector.eq(0).data("banana"));
```

Basically `.get(1)` will extract the second element as a node object from the jquery collection, whereas `.eq(1)` will get you the second element as a jquery object